# How to do an exclude django query on multiple foreign key

Tags: python, django

My model example:

```
class Thing(models.Model):

    alpha = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='alpha_thing')

    beta = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='beta_thing')
    assigned_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _('assigned at'),
        null=True,
        help_text=_('Assigned at this date'))
```

I wish to query all the users which don't have a Thing with an `assigned_at` date, ie they could have other Things, but that should have a date set.

I've tried:

```
return User.objects.exclude(
    alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=True
).exclude(
    beta_thing__assigned_at__isnull=True
).all()
```

but the result is empty (the thing table is empty, so i'm not sure if it has something to do with the join?).

Comment: Just to clarify: if I have this collection of Things [Thing(user1, user2, datetime), Thing(user2, user3, None)]... which users do you want? [user2, user3],  [user3]...?

Comment: @spadarian all the users which don't have a Thing with an empty date, so your example it would be not user2 and user3, so just user1 is expected.

Comment: I think you meant "all the users which don't have a Thing with**out** an `assigned_at` date" - is that correct?

Comment: Just to double check: you want to _include_ `User` objects which do _not_ have any related `alpha_thing` or `beta_thing` objects, right?

Answer (score 6):

What about this,

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(Q(alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False) | Q(beta_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False)).distinct()
```

### Screenshots

**1. Auth model structure - `User`**
[image: Auth Model]

**2. Thing model**
[image: Thing model data]

Answer (score 3):

There is another way, since you want to filter user which "things" contains all an `assigned_date`.

You could:

```
User.objects.filter(
    alpha_thign__assigned_at__isnull=False,
    beta_thign__assigned_at__isnull=False,
)
```

Simple.

There are no need to Use `Q` objects here or `|` (or) operations.

What you want is not

- `alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False` **OR**
- `beta_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False`

What you're looking for is

- `alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False` **AND**
- `beta_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False`

Answer (score 0):

For all users which don't have a Thing with an empty date try:

```
return User.objects.exclude(
    alpha_thing__assigned_at=None
).exclude(
    beta_thing__assigned_at=None
).all()
```

By the way, I got the same result whether I used `.all()` at the end or not, so:

```
return User.objects.exclude(
    alpha_thing__assigned_at=None
).exclude(
    beta_thing__assigned_at=None
)
```

returned the same result as the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
from django.db.models import Q

has_null_alpha = Q(alpha_thing__isnull=False, alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=True)

has_null_beta = Q(beta_thing__isnull=False, beta_thing__assigned_at__isnull=True)

User.objects.exclude(has_null_alpha | has_null_beta)
```

#### Reasoning

I think the reason you're seeing unexpected results may not have anything to do with the fact that there are multiple `ForeignKey` paths in the queryset.  Your statement that "the thing table is empty" might be the key, and the reason users aren't showing up is because **they have no `alpha_thing` or `beta_thing` relation**.

#### NOTES:

- The QuerySet `User.objects.exclude(alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=True)` produces a left outer join between the `User` table and the `Thing` table, which means that before doing any comparisons in the `WHERE` clause, you're getting `NULL` for `assigned_at` in any row where there is no `Thing`.
- One really weird thing here is that a `filter` causes an *INNER* join, so that the statement `User.objects.filter(alpha_thing__assigned_at__isnull=False)` actually only yields the users who actually *have* `alpha_thing` related objects with a non-`NULL` value for `assigned_at` (leaving out those guys with no related `alpha_thing`).